# WCF Client namespace issue

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I am trying to talk to a web service using a WCF client. I don't own/have access to the service end, it is third party.

Here is the problem I have: The service expects this:

```
<OTAX_PkgBookRQ PrimaryLangID="en" ActionType="Hold" Version="0" TransactionIdentifier="c4ca204f-754c-4de2-b28d-107c2a23322e" xmlns="http://api.codegen.net/ota/tbx">
    <PackageRequest ID="0">
        <UniqueID Type="User" ID="10344"></UniqueID>
        <UniqueID Type="Customer" ID="15489"></UniqueID>
        <ItineraryItems xmlns="http://api.codegen.net/ota/tbx">
            <ItineraryItem SwapItemNo="0" ItemNo="0" RPH="0:0">
                <ItemDetail>
                    <Flight>
                        <FlightSegments>
                            <FlightSegment RPH="0:0"></FlightSegment>
                            <FlightSegment RPH="1:0"></FlightSegment>
                        </FlightSegments>
                    </Flight>
                </ItemDetail>
            </ItineraryItem>
```

But my WCF client sends this:

```
    <OTAX_PkgBookRQ PrimaryLangID="en" ActionType="Hold" Version="0" TransactionIdentifier="c4ca204f-754c-4de2-b28d-107c2a23322e" xmlns="http://api.codegen.net/ota/tbx">
        <PackageRequest ID="0">
            <UniqueID Type="User" ID="10344"></UniqueID>
            <UniqueID Type="Customer" ID="15489"></UniqueID>
            <ItineraryItems>
                <ItineraryItem SwapItemNo="0" ItemNo="0" RPH="0:0">
                    <ItemDetail>
                        <Flight>
                            <FlightSegments>
                                <FlightSegment RPH="0:0"></FlightSegment>
                                <FlightSegment RPH="1:0"></FlightSegment>
                            </FlightSegments>
                        </Flight>
                    </ItemDetail>
                </ItineraryItem>
```

Note the omission of the namespace on `<ItineraryItems>` node

I'm pretty sure that the namespace is being 'omitted' because it is the namespace that is already in scope (from the `<OTAX_PkgBookRQ>` node). I have attempted to modify the node by using a message inspector, but the XmlNode instance already has the correct namespace specified.

Is there a way I can force WCF to output the namespace on a particular node?

EDIT: This may be helpful

This is the actual type of ItineraryItems (from reference.cs)

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18408")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://api.codegen.net/ota/tbx")]
public partial class PkgItineraryItemType : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
```

This is the 'inner' declaration (from reference.cs):

```
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order=4)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("ItineraryItem", IsNullable=false)]
    public PkgItineraryItemType[] ItineraryItems {
        get {
            return this.itineraryItemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itineraryItemsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ItineraryItems");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Namespace attribute to below part to 'inner' declaration

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(Namespace = "ttp://api.codegen.net/ota/tbx")]
```

e.g your code should look like this

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order=4)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("ItineraryItem", IsNullable=false)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(Namespace  = "http://api.codegen.net/ota/tbx")]

public PkgItineraryItemType[] ItineraryItems {
    get {
        return this.itineraryItemsField;
    }
    set {
        this.itineraryItemsField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("ItineraryItems");
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the 'inner' property declaration has the same namespace as the 'outer' class declaration so it looks like WCF suppresses the namespaces that are the same (i.e. in scope).